# What is grunt serve capable of doing with connect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I am working on a project on a remote server since I need python and DB resources that my local machine can't access.

I've read this page a few times now:
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect

... and can't find out what is meant by some of the terms.

In my Gruntfile.js I see:

```
// The actual grunt server settings
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },
```

√ <s>What exactly does "outside" mean?</s>     got it

√ <s>What is "the server" referring to?</s>    got it

I am running `grunt serve` on a linux remote server and want to see my project livereload in my web browser. What URL should I use in the browser and what should the Gruntfile contain? Is this even possible?

When I run `http://MyRemoteHostName:9000/` while using `0.0.0.0` as the hostname setting, the DNS address cannot be found.

Note that the apache web server/python code repository on my remote host is exposed to the web via another URL like `http://special.development.url.com` but this fails to show the app as well:
`http://special.development.url.com:9000`

Comment: `outside` of the machine running server, in your case - linux remote machine, you're `outside` of it

Comment: ok so I change it to 0.0.0.0 ... now it is accessible from the outside in theory. By what means? I know my remote IP, my personal mac IP, do I use one or both of these to see the web app in my browser?

Comment: how did you edited this file on server? did you sshed to it?

Comment: Right, I SSH in and do my work there.

Comment: ok, to ssh you've used something like `ssh REMOTEHOSTNAME`, now you need to open `http://REMOTEHOSTNAME:9000/` in your browser

Comment: I updated the answer, noting that this failed. I think that would require some kind of additional DNS mapping, SSH port forwarding, etc. I have a URL that is pointed to this server's apache/python CGI environment, but adding port 9000 to that URL fails as well.

Comment: as soon as you can ssh to this host, but cannot resolve this hostname directly, probably you're using some proxy/tunnel, you can create ssh tunnel like `ssh -24gvN -L 9000:localhost:9000 REMOTEHOSTNAME` and then use `http://localhost:9000/` in your browser

Comment: oh my GOD. that worked brilliantly. Thanks so much. Would gladly accept this as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly does "outside" mean?

A different computer.

The default is `localhost` which (unless you use some kind of port forwarding such as ssh tunnelling) can only be accessed from the computer it is running on. `0.0.0.0` means **all** the network interfaces in the computer (including any ethernet and wifi connections).

> What is "the server" referring to?

The description of grunt-contrib-connect is *Start a connect web server*. That is the server it is talking about.